# Extract number of string with regex

Tags: regex

I am having a problem with regex. My goal is to get the number whenever a number is staying behind those chars:

1. ‚G ‘
2. ‚H ‘
3. ‚S ‘
4. ‚T ‘
5. ‚T26 ‘
6. ‚T‘
7. ‚W ‘

So you can see, we have 6 times the case having a whitespace and one case (number 6) where we don't have a whitespace to match.

I was trying to create a regex for case 4. and 6. This is my regex so far:

```
/[T](?:\ )?\d+/
```

Or this is also another solution I got so far:

```
/([T](?:\ )|([GHSW]|(T26))\ )?\d+/
```

However, I don't get the number, I also do get the char T back.. How can I get only the number back and is there any easy solution to have one regex matching all of the chars instead of creating 6 regex if statements..?

Example Input:

> Hello my name G 25 is Alfred. I am H 26 testing a new regex S2 and S 5
>   this is my T3 test T 4 regex text. My T26 2 and my T265 is a new W2
>   and also W 4.

What I want (output):

1. The 25 after the G
2. The 26 after the H
3. The 5 after the S (not the 2 cause there is not a whitespace between the S and the digit. This also goes for the G, H, S and W)
4. The 3 and 4 after the T (if it is a T, there can be a whitespace but doesn't have to)
5. The 2 after the T26 (but not the 5 or 265 after the T265 cause there needs to be a whitespace after the T26)

Kind regards and Thank You!

Comment: Please provide more diverse sample input, the desired result and some info on environment. Which regex flavor? Which shell?

Comment: Please demonstrate how you apply your (nonworking) regex. Show the commandline. Especially interesting is the name of the tool you use.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't really understand your requirement. What's your expected output? Do you want to extract ```4. ,``` and ```6. ,``` because T has 26 behind it at index 5?

Comment: I have add an example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This regex should do what you want. It looks for one of

1. `[GHSW]` followed by a space, or
2. `T26` followed by a space, or
3. `T` followed by an optional space

and some digits, which are captured in group 1:

```
(?:[GHSW]\s|T26\s|T(?!26)\s?)(\d+)
```

[Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/LmVFhR/4)

If you only want to capture the digits in the match and your regex flavour supports lookbehinds, you can use this instead:

```
(?<=[GHSW]\s|T26\s|T(?!26) |T(?!26))\d+
```

Note that we have to specify both `T` with a space and without separately to ensure that the lookbehind is fixed width.

[Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/pRxEZ8/1)

Comment: @Jan I've updated my answer based on your example. I think it matches what you want now.

Comment: Yeah.. almost.. If there is a G, H, S, W or a T26 there has to be a whitespace between the char and the number to be a valid match. Only if it is a T it doesn't matter if there is a whitespace between the T and the number. How can I extract this?

Comment: @Jan that is what this regex looks for. It matches everything in your example (including the `4` after `W` which you don't mention)

Comment: Sweet, I just saw it too! You helped me a lot, thanks!

Comment: Is there also a way to ignore the full match and ONLY get the Group 1 returned by the regex?

Comment: @Jan You can do it but it's messy, you need to use 4 different positive lookbehinds `(?<=[GHSW]\s)\d+|(?<=T26\s)\d+|(?<=T(?!26))\d+|(?<=T(?!26)\s)\d+` https://regex101.com/r/LmVFhR/5/

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi that was my first inclination but I thought that it would violate the requirement that lookbehinds must have a fixed width and `G ` is not the same width as `T26 `. I see from your demo that is not the case though... I guess I've learnt something new today.

Comment: Basically you can take positive look behind part as common and make the regex shorter. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/pRxEZ8/1) Yes, Nick, since `?` makes the regex variable width, you can have two regex parts one with space and one without space, and that way it fulfills the condition and doesn't remain variable width :)

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi thanks for your input (and upvote!). I've updated my answer with your lookbehind solution too.

Comment: Whats the difference to your solution @Nick? If I got it right, it is the same result just not as messy as your solution in the comment?

Comment: @Jan that's exactly right. It is exactly the same thing written less messily because I thought you couldn't have different length strings in a lookbehind (hence I had 4 different lookbehinds) but in fact you can.